# Writing text expanding (pyramid)

Tags: javascript, html

Hey sorry for my bad english.

I need a code that uses loop to print this kind of output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

It's like counting from 1 to 10 but instead of numbers it makes * show the value.

I did a lot of research but I couldn't find a right thing to use to make a loop that count from any number I want and make it look like that input.

Comment: Are you using VB or JS, question says 1, tag says another

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: javascript sorry can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is rather simple. All you need is a `for` loop that:

1. iterates as many times as designated,
2. uses [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to create as many asterisks as the row number &
3. adds the newline character `"\n"` at the end of the string.

**Example:**

```js
/* The function that creates the desired output for as many rows as given. */
function createOutput(rows) {
  /* Create an empty string. */
  var str = "";
  
  /* Loop [rows] times and add [i] asterisks & a newline to the string each loop. */
  for (var i = 1; i <= rows; str += "*".repeat(i) + "\n", i++);
  
  /* Return the string. */
  return str;
}

/* Create an output of 5 rows and log it in the console. */
console.log(createOutput(5));
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Since [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) was added in EcmaScript 6, it may not work for everyone. If you encounter that problem, you can supplant `"*".repeat(i)` with `Array(i+1).join("*")`.
2. In order to include the above code in your application you have to:

   - save it in a file and load that using:
      `<script src = "file.js" type = "application/javascript"></script>`
   - or paste it inside in your `HTML` file using:
      `<script type = "application/javascript">[the code]</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can simply use one **for** loop and the **repeat** function together :

```js
function pyramid(max, c) {
    r = "";
    for(i=1; i<=max; i++) {
        r = r + c.repeat(i) + "\n";
    }
    return r;
}

console.log(pyramid(10, '*'));
```

Use : pyramid(*length*, *char*);

```
var my result = pyramid(10, '*');
```